# AS3 Flash: How to update custom class instance?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, instance

I'm using AS3.0 with Flash (not Flex). I have created a custom class called drawBarChart and have created an instance called BarChart1.

```
var BarChart1 = new drawBarChart(barChartX, barChartY, barChartWidth, barChartHeight, barChartScale)
```

If I change the value of the variable barChartScale later in the code the BarChart1 instance doesn't change.  Can someone please explain to me what the right syntax is to get the BarChart1 instance to update with the new value of barChartScale?

Thanks!

EDIT: Thank you Loxxy and shaunhusain for your replies.  I've tried implementing your approach Loxxy, but it's still not quite working for me yet.  Through some trace statements, I can see that I get the _Scale variable to change reflected within the custom class setChartScale function.  But the resulting _Scale change does not seem to be reflected in the custom class BarChart function where the instance was originally created.  i.e. the scale value on the instance doesn't change for me yet.  I will continue to work at it!

Comment: Just some things to note since your name says you're an AS3 noob.  You're not doing anything that is strictly wrong here in terms of syntax but the convention in all OOP languages I've used (C++, Java, and AS3) is to name your classes with an upper case character to start and then use camel case for the variable, property, and method names (difference between these three is basically contextual as well, exposed variables like you're looking for are properties, methods/functions can have whatever scope).  In your case above barChart1 and DrawBarChart is how I would name them (see loxxy answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to expose the scale property to access later.

Nothing special to Action Script here, just a coding practice. Implement it something like this:

```
public class BarChart 
    {    
        var _Scale:Number;

        public function BarChart(barChartX, barChartY, barChartWidth, barChartHeight, barChartScale) 
        {
            // Set other properties...

            _Scale = barChartScale;

        }

        public function setChartScale(scale:Number)
        {
            _Scale = scale; 
        }    
    }
```

Now use it as:

```
        var chart = new BarChart(0,0,80,80,1);

        chart.setChartScale(1.5);     // At a later point..
```